# Ms Excel VBA: Set a sorting combo box

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am new to VBA although I have some experience in Visual Basic.
I have a Microsoft Excel 2010 worksheet. Row 29 has the headers of a table and the data is from row 30 and so on. This table has like 20 columns.

I'm trying to insert a combo in this Worksheet with three options, so when you choose the first, it will apply descending sorting to all the table according to column R and then column S. If you choose the second, it will apply descending sorting according to column S and then column R. If you choose the first it will apply descending sorting according to column A.
Column S and Column R will be hidden.
I hope you guys can help me out. Thank you and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put a picture to words, I assume you have an excel sheet that looks similar like this:

[image: Initial ScreenShot of Worksbook]

(Keeping columns S and R visible for this example)

You want to add a combo box that will sort columns based on the value selected in the combo box that will be like so:

- **Option 1**:  Sort descending on column R, then S
- **Option 2**:  Sort descending on column S, then R
- **Option 3**:  Sort descending on column A.

First thing, if you haven't already done so, is add the [Developer Tab to Excel](http://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/how-to-add-developer-tab.html#developertab2010).

Next, put cells from the table in a Named Range.  If the rows in this table will change, then make sure you create a [dynamic named range](http://www.contextures.com/xlnames01.html). (*Dynamic Named Ranges are a little tricky, but very useful for dynamic data*)

Add the combo box by clicking Insert from the *Developer Tab* and select combo box from **Form Controls** (**NOTE:**  An ActiveX combobox is a completely different type of control.  You could come to the same result using it, but the code would be different.)

Drag the combobox somewhere on the worksheet:
[image: Add combo box]

Now add the options values to the combo.  You should go somewhere in your workbook and add the values for you combo box  (e.g. Sheet2, Cells A1, A2 & A3).

[image: Combo box values]

Return to your sheet where the table and combo box reside.  Right-click on the combo box and select **Format Control**.

[image]

The input range range should be the cells containing your sorting options.  It look something like this:  *Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3*

Right click on the combo box again and select **Assign Macro**.  Give the Macro a name and put the Macro in *This Workbook*

[image: Macro]

Click New.  You will be taken to the Visual Basic Editor.

Here you can apply your sorting code:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub DropDown2_Change()
        Dim comboValue As String
        Dim Key1ColumnIndex As Integer
        Dim Key2ColumnIndex As Integer

        'You can get the name by doing something like this in the immediate window:  "? Sheet1.Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Name"
        comboValue = Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 2").ControlFormat.List(Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 2").ControlFormat.ListIndex)

        Select Case comboValue

            Case "Option1"
                Key1ColumnIndex = 18
                Key2ColumnIndex = 19
            Case "Option2"
                Key1ColumnIndex = 19
                Key2ColumnIndex = 18
            Case "Option3"
                Key1ColumnIndex = 1
                Key2ColumnIndex = 1
        End Select


       Range("DataValues").Sort Key1:=Range("DataValues").Cells(1, Key1ColumnIndex), _
                                Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
                                Key2:=Range("DataValues").Cells(1, Key2ColumnIndex), order2:=xlDescending
    End Sub
```

You should be now be good to go.  If you need a working example, take a look at the sample sheet I created [here](http://www.o1solution.com/excel_help.zip); note that it does not have a dynamic name range for the table.

Comment: Thanks @ray023 This is incredibly helpful. Just one more question. I want to define this macro in a template so a third party application fills up several sheets with different amounts of data and sets personalized names to the sheets. How would you work with the data range if you don't know how much data you're getting? How would you make this work for several sheets in the same workbook? Thanks again!

Comment: I would have to ask more questions to give a full answer.  Generally, if the schema doesn't change (e.g. A sheet named "Customers" will always be present and the columns will not change), then your predefined dynamic range should work.  If you want to delve deeper, you could probably create the dynamic range based off the data being imported, but that's something better suited for a new question than a comment.  Also, if possible (which I know we aren't always given this luxury), I would look into putting the data in a database (e.g. Access); much easier way to maintain data.